# vagrant windows folder setup

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

I'm setting up vagrant on my Windows 7 and configuring Vagrantfile. Can I set the actual folder and guest folder to be the same? Here is my code:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "C:\Users\dmitry\VM\code", "/vagrant/code"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. I used the config like below and it worked beautifully:

`config.vm.synced_folder "C:/git/ui", "/home/vagrant/ui"`